# How do I change this to integration over a trajectory?

Tags: chaos-theory, lyapunov-functions

I'm working through *CHAOS: An Introduction to Dynamical Systems* by Alligood et. al. and I'm on Challenge 7 step 5. At this point we have a system of ODEs. (Note: a dot over a variable is its derivative with respect to time).

$$\begin{align*}
\dot{x} & = z - \left(\frac{x^3}{3} - x\right) \\
\dot{z} & = -x
\end{align*}.$$

We also have an energy function

$$E(x, z) = \frac{1}{2}\left(x^2+z^2\right).$$

I've been able to prove that

$$\dot{E} = \left(\frac{x^3}{3} - x\right) \dot{z}$$

using the chain rule. But, then, the book seems to be asking me to show something I can't quite get. If $X$ is a trajectory of the system of ODEs and $X_0$ a segment of it starting at $(x_1, z_1)$ and ending at $(x_2, z_2)$ then I'm supposed to show that

$$E(x_2, z_2) - E(x_1, z_1) = \int_{X_0}{\left(\frac{x^3}{3} - x\right) \dot{z}dt}.$$

Now  here is my issue. I can understand if the statement is

$$E(x_2, z_2) - E(x_1, z_1) = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}{\left(\frac{x^3}{3} - x\right) \dot{z}dt}$$

where $t_1$ and $t_2$ are the times corresponding to the ends of $X_0$. But, how do I get to integrating over the segment of the trajectory as opposed to integrating over time?

Note: the book is actually asking me to prove something slightly different, but it would require a good amount of more setup and I think this amounts to the same thing.

Comment: @Gonçalo right. So, then, if I wanted to actually evaluate the integral, I'd need solve the system of ODEs and then either integrate with respect to time and use $dt$ or integrate with respect to $X_0$ and solve for $dX$ in terms of $dt$, right?

Comment: @Gonçalo thanks! That absolutely helps me compute this! Conceptually, I think I figured out my issue. When we have $dt$ I'm used to the integral being "over $t$". However, once I thought about this in terms of Riemann Sums it helped. If I divide up the trajectory into little chunks, $(x_0, z_0), (x_1, z_1), ..., (x_n, z_n)$ then I can just do the regular Riemann sum via 

$$E(x(t_2), z(t_2)) - E(x(t_2), z(t_2)) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}{\dot{E}(x_i, z_i) \Delta t_i}$$

the trick is that I need to remember that $\Delta t_i$ is not constant. Is that right?